# Setting doc_values for _id field in elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to set doc_values for _id field in elastic search As want to perform sorting based on _id

hitting below api to update mapping gives me an error

```
PUT my_index/my_type/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "_id": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "doc_values": true
      }
    }  
}
```

reason : Mapping definition for [_id] has unsupported parameters:  [doc_value : true]

Answer (score 2):

It is “doc_values”, you are using an incorrect parameter. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html

Elastic discourages sorting on _id field. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html)

*The value of the _id field is also accessible in aggregations or for sorting, but doing so is discouraged as it requires to load a lot of data in memory. In case sorting or aggregating on the _id field is required, it is advised to duplicate the content of the _id field in another field that has doc_values enabled.*

**EDIT**

Create a scripted field for your index pattern with name for. ex `id` of type `string` and script `doc['_id'].value`. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html) link for more information on scripted fields. This will create a new field `id` and copy `_id` field's value for every document indexed into your indices matching your index pattern. You can then perform sorting on `id` field.

Comment: Corrected doc_values, still getting an error Field [_id] is defined twice in [type]. There is no field with _id in my mapping

Comment: how can I copy _id value to a different field?

Comment: even copying _id gives me same error, how can I use elasticsearch meta fields